How to create a folder, then shortcuts based on values in Excel?
I'm currently working on a script to perform these steps:

Import the sheet using the import-excel module
Find a number in sheet
Find customer in sheet
find customer in shortcuts folder
Create a folder for the customer if one doesn't exist
create shortcut inside that folder named the number from step 1, that links to the new location (This is a part of an archiving solution that I'm trying to build)

I've managed to come up with this, which works - somewhat. The problem I'm having is that it's not looping as I would expect, and the script ends after just creating one shortcut in a customer folder.
Excessive googling and a few hours later, I haven't had much luck, so I'm definitely missing something.
$WshShell = New-Object -COMObject WScript.Shell

$Excelsheet = "C:\Data\examplefolder\file.xlsm"
$ShortcutFolder = "C:\Data\examplefolder\ShortcutLocation"

$projectNumber = Import-Excel $Excelsheet -WorksheetName "2024" -NoHeader -DataOnly -StartRow 3 -EndRow 90 -StartColumn 2 -EndColumn 2
$customer = Import-Excel $Excelsheet -WorksheetName "2024" -NoHeader -DataOnly -StartRow 3 -EndRow 90 -StartColumn 3 -EndColumn 3

Foreach($number in $projectNumber) {
    $customerFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $ShortcutFolder -Directory
    New-Item ItemType Directory -Path "$shortcutfolder\$customer"
    $newShortcutPath = Join-Path -Path $customerFolder.FullName -ChildPath "$folder.lnk"
    $Shortcut = $WshShell.CreateShortcut($newshortcutPath)
    $Shortcut.TargetPath = $folder.FullName
    $Shortcut.Save()
}

I've tried messing for the foreach parameters, since that's my main suspicion of where I've gone wrong as it's creating a folder and shortcut, just not looping.
I've also tried creating another import variable to get only the column with customers instead of the column with numbers, and using  New-Item -Type SymbolicLink  instead of using wshshell which resulted in permission issues.

You never define variable $folder...

Not a solution--just something to try . . .
Write-Host $projectNumber
after assigning the value.  It may not be what you expect.  Then, as the first line in the loop:
Write-Host $number

You could also put this into vscode and use the debugger to stop and inspect variables.

This was enough to put me on the right track - thank you! I've made progress since :)
